# My BF to NASM compiler makes asm that doesn't work, for a known working BF program

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm, brainfuck

**Meta**: I am new to assembly language in general and NASM in particular. After playing around with NASM for a couple of evenings I got confident enough to write a simple Brainf*uck compiler: it takes bf code as an input and spits back some NASM code. The compiler is written in Python.

**Problem**: The compiler seems to be working for simple cases - for instance, the "Helloworld" program (listing below). In other cases, e.g. the famous Mandelbrot program segfaults badly pretty soon after the invocation.

I am using an extremely straight forward approach:

- As a current memory pointer I am using the `r10` register
- The bf tape itself corresponds to the `memory` label.
- To slide across the tape (`<` and `>` operations) I do `add/sub r10, value`, e.g. `add r10, 10`
- To modify the tape contents I do `add/sub byte [memory+r10], byte value`

**Question**: Can you spot anything completely wrong right away? I am not providing the NASM output for the Mandelbrot (which segfaults) because it is rather lengthy.

```
global _start


section .data
    memory: times 32768 db 0


section .text
_start:
    xor r10, r10
    call l0
    mov rax, 60
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall

    l1: ; [>+++++++>++++++++++>+++>+<<<<-]
        add r10, 1
        add byte [memory+r10], byte 7
        add r10, 1
        add byte [memory+r10], byte 10
        add r10, 1
        add byte [memory+r10], byte 3
        add r10, 1
        add byte [memory+r10], byte 1
        sub r10, 4
        sub byte [memory+r10], byte 1
        cmp byte [r10+memory], byte 0
        jne l1
        ret
    l0: ; ++++++++++[>+++++++>++++++++++>+++>+<<<<-]>++.>+.+++++++..+++.>++.<<+++++++++++++++.>.+++.------.--------.>+.
        add byte [memory+r10], byte 10
        call l1
        add r10, 1
        add byte [memory+r10], byte 2
        mov rax, 1
        mov rdi, 1
        lea rsi, [r10+memory]
        mov rdx, 1
        syscall
        add r10, 1
        add byte [memory+r10], byte 1
        mov rax, 1
        mov rdi, 1
        lea rsi, [r10+memory]
        mov rdx, 1
        syscall
        add byte [memory+r10], byte 7
        mov rax, 1
        mov rdi, 1
        lea rsi, [r10+memory]
        mov rdx, 1
        syscall
        mov rax, 1
        mov rdi, 1
        lea rsi, [r10+memory]
        mov rdx, 1
        syscall
        add byte [memory+r10], byte 3
        mov rax, 1
        mov rdi, 1
        lea rsi, [r10+memory]
        mov rdx, 1
        syscall
        add r10, 1
        add byte [memory+r10], byte 2
        mov rax, 1
        mov rdi, 1
        lea rsi, [r10+memory]
        mov rdx, 1
        syscall
        sub r10, 2
        add byte [memory+r10], byte 15
        mov rax, 1
        mov rdi, 1
        lea rsi, [r10+memory]
        mov rdx, 1
        syscall
        add r10, 1
        mov rax, 1
        mov rdi, 1
        lea rsi, [r10+memory]
        mov rdx, 1
        syscall
        add byte [memory+r10], byte 3
        mov rax, 1
        mov rdi, 1
        lea rsi, [r10+memory]
        mov rdx, 1
        syscall
        sub byte [memory+r10], byte 6
        mov rax, 1
        mov rdi, 1
        lea rsi, [r10+memory]
        mov rdx, 1
        syscall
        sub byte [memory+r10], byte 8
        mov rax, 1
        mov rdi, 1
        lea rsi, [r10+memory]
        mov rdx, 1
        syscall
        add r10, 1
        add byte [memory+r10], byte 1
        mov rax, 1
        mov rdi, 1
        lea rsi, [r10+memory]
        mov rdx, 1
        syscall
        ret
```

### Update:

The recent version of the translator can be found [here](https://github.com/magniff/maxfucktor).

Comment: Use a debugger. Also, reduce your mandelbrot to a minimal case that produces the error and post that. From looking at this code, your `r10` probably goes outside of the allocated block size, for whatever reason.

Comment: In NASM terminology, generating a *listing* is when you assemble with `nasm -l foo.lst  -felf64 foo.asm`, producing a listing of machine code and source lines.  (Like in [this code-golf answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/214750/display-the-exponent-from-a-binary-floating-point-number-as-a-decimal-value/214818#214818), for example).  What you're doing is *compiling* BF into NASM, generating NASM *source*.  So the question title was a bit confusing: you're not using NASM to generate listings.

Comment: If you want to include a link to your compiler hobby project, feel free.  Others might be interested.  I haven't seen most BF compilers use call/ret.  e.g. this codereview [Brainfreeze: A Brainfuck compiler in C](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/215574).  Note that you could save code-size if you kept a pointer in `r10` instead of an index, and if you used a register that didn't need a REX prefix.  So you could use `add byte [rbx], 10` or whatever, no 32-bit displacement needed in every memory instruction.

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks for your helpful comments. In the `update` section you can find a link to the recent version of the translator, although there's not much to look at, really.

Comment: You can call it a "compiler", because high-level source to asm or machine code translation = compilation.  It's a fairly simple compiler, but does even do some optimization of runs of the same symbol into one `add`/`sub` instead of multiple `inc` or `dec` insns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out - the problem was in a slight misunderstanding of BF logic itself.
In example above the `l1` label should look like this:

```
    l1: ; [>+++++++>++++++++++>+++>+<<<<-]
        cmp byte [memory+r10], byte 0
        jne .cont
        ret
        .cont:
        add r10, 1
        add byte [memory+r10], byte 7
        add r10, 1
        add byte [memory+r10], byte 10
        add r10, 1
        add byte [memory+r10], byte 3
        add r10, 1
        add byte [memory+r10], byte 1
        sub r10, 4
        sub byte [memory+r10], byte 1
        cmp byte [memory+r10], byte 0
        jne l1
        ret
```